# Resolving dependencies for migration AEM 6.0 to 6.2

Tags: aem, sling, aem-6

Hi I have trying to start the bundle in 6.2 as part of migration from 6.0.

I have included UBER jar and still bundle is not started.

[image]

com.day.cq.replication,version=[5.5,6)-- this is the error.

Answer (score 1):

Following is available in AEM 6.2 and that's what your POM should reflect -

For CQ Replication

```
<groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
<artifactId>com.adobe.granite.replication.core</artifactId>
<version>6.0.14</version>
```

Comment: if I add that version, The below is showing up while compiling   
Failed to execute goal on project company-bundle: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.x:company-bundle:bundle:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.adobe.granite:com.adobe.granite.replication.core:jar:6.0.14 in adobe-public-releases (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Add scope as provided in dependency

Comment: Download the jar from crx and upload it to your local nexus